# Android Google maps co-ordinates

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an app which stores co-ordinates. I am using Google maps to show the location to allow full use of the maps app. I am using the intent call and placing the co-ordinates in the q=xxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx part.

This works, however when Google maps shows the location it often finds a point on the road, sometimes a little distance from the actual co-ordinates.

Is there a way to get maps to show the actual point?

Comment: I would assume that google maps shows the actual coordinates and the coordinates you are supplying are somewhat inaccurate. How do you get the coordinates you want to show?

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.mygeoposition.com). it helps.

Comment: I can guarentee the co-ordinates are correct - they come from two sources - one is the app its self (GPS location, shown on a map and saved), the other is a list supplied - I have verified the locations of a few testers using both the phones GPS status, a TomTom device and also a Garmin GPS device.

The location google maps shows seems to be the nearest location it knows if there is one it knows in the area.

Take this link as an example - on the pc it shows two markers the green arrow being the actual location, the phone shows just the bubble (A)

http://maps.google.com/?q=51.554874,-0.402374

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that doesn't really help with the app - it shows the link simply provides google with a question (q=) of the co-ordinates, so it seems to just show somewhere it knows rather than the exact location given.

Comment: when search the name of the building on that site. you will get the co-ordinates of the building. you can get the lat and long wherever you want. just click on that location buddy.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I came across right in my question - I already have the correct co-ordinates saved in a database - I don't need to find details for an address. What I want is to be able to pass a co-ordinate to the maps application without it finding the nearest road to the co-ordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=(@24.397611,120.780512)

from

http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters

Comment: That's not quite what I was looking for with using an intent call to open the map's app, but it has just answered another question I had excellently! If you change the 'question' to, for example, `q=Grass Verge@51.554874,-0.402374` Not only does it place the marker exactly where it should be, it puts Grass Verge as the address in the marker, something I had wanted to do on a previous project! Thanks for the answer!!