# Google maps link produces slightly moved marker when opened with native iphone/android app

Tags: android, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am building a web app which contains a Google Maps link that can be opened by the native phone Maps app (iPhone/Android).

The link has the form: 
`http://maps.google.com/?q="+startCooLat+','+startCooLng;`
and I have also tried the: 
`http://maps.google.com/?q=loc:"+startCooLat+'+'+startCooLng;`

However in the native app the marker is positioned in the nearest street and not in the exact coordinates that I am giving. Is there a solution or another parameter to set so as to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of [questioning **(q=.....)**](http://querystring.org/google-maps-query-string-parameters/) google maps for the location, in which it returns what it thinks is the nearest human address to the location *(somewhat annoying I think)* you can pass a lat lng location where you want the center of the map to be. For example:

http://maps.google.co.uk/?ll=53.385517,-1.865315

Instead of:

http://maps.google.co.uk/?q=53.385517,-1.865315

I had this problem my self, and on my Android device at least this works. The second example simply puts the map on a road, the first is in the middle of the moors on the device in the maps app.

---

The full link from the comments:

http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=53.385517,-1.865315&q=loc:53.385517,-1.865315&t=m

This one seems to work at adding a marker for the standard maps app whilst still adding a marker.

---

After receiving a recent answer to an old Android Google Maps question I had, I have found another solution to this question, which I thought would be useful for others. [Original Question - and credit to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808496/android-google-maps-co-ordinates/8598679#8598679) [Captain Charmi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/914130/captain-charmi) for pointing me in the direction.

Instead of using the link above which will create a marker at the given location, trouble is, the maker is pretty meaningless, just the coordinates. If you use the following link, you can add either a title to the marker and show the coordinates:

[http://maps.google.com/maps?q=53.385517,-1.865315+(My Random Location)](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=53.385517,-1.865315+(My%20Random%20Location))

Or you can instead of adding a title, you can supply text to go inside the marker:

[http://maps.google.com/maps?q=A pot of gold at the end of a rainbow@53.385517,-1.865315](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=A%20pot%20of%20gold%20at%20the%20end%20of%20a%20rainbow!@53.385517,-1.865315)

As you can see, Google now drops the marker in the correct place due to being supplied the info for the marker. I hope this helps.

Comment: But this does not generate a marker, right? it sets the center of the map. I would like to generate a marker as well

Comment: After doing a bit of playing, this appears to be working on my desire: http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=53.385517,-1.865315&q=loc:53.385517,-1.865315&t=m and gives you a marker at the location.

Comment: No problem at all, glad to have helped out :)

Comment: In case its any use I have added two new methods, both work extremely well on the Android maps app!